# Android: Same resource IDs being used in Custom ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-resources

I'm creating a custom array adapter my ListView and I notice that the resource ID `R.id.txt_item_eng` I'm assigning to each `englishWordTextView` inside my `itemListView` seems to be the same? If I have a list of views within a ListView, shouldn't their ID's all be different somehow? I'm just trying to update each item with a new English word.

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

    public WordAdapter(Context context, List objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemListView = convertView; //Recycle old view

        ....
        // Word is a custom class
        Word w = getItem(position); It's specified in `extends ArrayAdapter<Word>`

        // Update English word
        TextView englishWordTextView = (TextView) itemListView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_eng);
        englishWordTextView.setText(w.getEnglishWord());

        return itemListView;
    }
}
```

Another question here I guess is, if every word `TextView` has an ID of `R.id.txt_item_eng`, how do I reference them outside of the `itemListView`?

Answer (score 2):

This is how `ListView` or any `AdapterView` works . Same view will inflate for each item . Each widget which have `Adapter` implementation in android have there own way to access the item at particular position .

For instance if you want to get click on each position you can set `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // position is the item clicked
        }
    });
```

Also each `ListAdapter` class have methods to access items like `getItem(position)` from which you can return the object of your dataset for particular position .

From my understanding you should learn about `ListView` and `ViewHolder` pattern first .
You can read [This Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling) or some similar one . If you do not understand the concept behind `ListView` then this answer can be way too big . SO its better you should check out some samples and Documentation.

**P.S**:- Ditch `ListView` now and start using `RecyclerView` . Here is the [Google-Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView) for `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView is a collection of views, and must be populated by using an [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter). It looks like you're on the right track but you may not understand all the components of this pattern. There should be no reason to reference the TextView from outside the adapter. The `getView()` method you've got there is responsible for inflating the layout of the row in the ListView. This is where you set the text and any other visible elements of the row.

The `getItem()` method (which I see you're calling but you haven't included the declaration), is where you can access the data of the item (think model in [MVC pattern](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/mvc)).

Here is a [very handy tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) that might make this a little easier to understand.